# Error in Writter - Writer no open

Tags: libreoffice

When i try start `libreoffice --writer` in terminal i receive this error

```
** (soffice:8154): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

after this, writer close unexpectedly

If i use the desktop shortcut, only show the libreoffice5 splash screen and nothing more happend.

I need writer work fine. i was looking in google but i dont find any clue to fix this problem. Can anybody helpme?.-

My OS Version is

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu (lubuntu)
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
libreoffice-writer i386 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5
```

Sorry by my english. i wrote from Chile.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA is causing this, there's a quick workaround just launch *Libbre Office* itself ***"not" the Writer*** with any app launcher that you're using click *Tools* --> *Options* --> *Advanced* and remove the ***tick*** to use *Java Runtime*

[image: sample]